# how to remove last text in parenthesis (elegantly and simply)

Tags: f#

So I have some working code.

I want to remove the last parenthesized (?) text from a string...as long as its "the last" (i.e. isnt followed by whitespace or a full stop).

so

```
let x1 = remove "hello how are you.   "
let x2 = remove "hello how are you. (remove me)   "
let x3 = remove "hello how are you(don't remove me!).,   "
```

goes to

```
val x1 : string = "hello how are you.   "
val x2 : string = "hello how are you.    "
val x3 : string = "hello how are you(don't remove me!).,   "
```

I need to do this in language that doesnt support regex and is (sort of) functional, and is pretty basic.
(its XSLT 1.0)

I don't really like hacking in XSLT, so I've hacked together a simple routine in f#.

```
let remove s = 
    match (s : string).LastIndexOf '(' with
    | -1 ->
        s
    | lastOpen ->
        let rest = s.Substring lastOpen
        match rest.LastIndexOf ')' with
        | -1 -> 
            s
        | lastClose -> 
            let after = rest.Substring (lastClose + 1)
            if after.Replace(".","") |> String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace then
                s.Substring (0,lastOpen) + after
            else
                s
```

I can't use Regex, (or write some sort of parser), its just a basic as simple as possible algorithm.

The above broadly works (I can see an edge case it doesnt...but don't get too hung up).

Anything simpler (but less ugly)?

EDIT #1 post accepting reply.

as a sobering thought this is the xslt version of a 4 line f# program!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="foo">
      <xsl:call-template name="removeParenthesisIf">
        <xsl:with-param name="s" select="'foo bar dfsfsfffs)'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="maxCount" select="20"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="removeParenthesisIf">
    <xsl:param name="s"/>
    <xsl:param name="maxCount"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="substring($s,string-length($s)) = ')'">
        <xsl:variable name="lastOpen">
          <xsl:call-template name="lastCharIndex">
            <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$s"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pChar" select="'('"/>
          </xsl:call-template>          
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="($maxCount &gt; string-length($s) - $lastOpen + 1) and not(string-length($s) = $lastOpen )">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($s,1,$lastOpen - 1)"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$s"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="lastCharIndex">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>
    <xsl:param name="pChar" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vRev">
      <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="$pText"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-length($pText) - string-length(substring-before($vRev, $pChar))"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="reverse">
    <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vLength" select="string-length($pStr)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$vLength = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$pStr"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="vHalfLength" select="floor($vLength div 2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vrevHalf1">
          <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
            <xsl:with-param name="pStr"
                 select="substring($pStr, 1, $vHalfLength)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="vrevHalf2">
          <xsl:call-template name="reverse">
            <xsl:with-param name="pStr"
                 select="substring($pStr, $vHalfLength+1)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($vrevHalf2, $vrevHalf1)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing something along those lines that I can think of, using mainly the built-in string functions, is the following:

```
let remove (s:string) = 
  if s.TrimEnd(' ').EndsWith(")") then
    let last = s.LastIndexOf('(')
    s.Remove(last, s.LastIndexOf(')') - last + 1)
  else s
```

There are two tricks:

- First, we check if the string ends with `)` if we remove all spaces from the end. This is detecting the case where you have something to remove.
- If that's the case, you can remove a substring from the middle using `Remove`. This assumes that the string is well-formed and does actually have an opening parenthesis - so that's an extra check you may need to add.

Comment: better than mine!

Comment: lets go with this...I may have to tweak it a bit, but your 4 lines easily beats my 12, just see how easy it is to transliterate it into xslt...but I wanted the simplest basic algorithm

Comment: I've transliterated it...its now 75 codes of ugly XSLT...actually I had to do a reverse to do LastIndexOf....so maybe a double reverse approach would have worked better in XSLT, but this is elegant enough.